# Java program for lucky draw

Tags: java, random, arraylist

There are 5 people and 5 things. 5 people are

```
Mg Mg, Su Su, Zaw Zaw, Kyaw Kyaw, Mya Mya
```

5 things are

```
Iphone, mp3, tv and two thank you
```

I want each person to get a thing randomly like lucky draw every time I run this in Java. I can't get the same people to get the same thing if I run the second time. I am not sure if I can use the array method for names or things to store them.

Can you tell me how to do that? Can I get the code if possible?

I've already tried this but have no idea how to continue.

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
name.add("Mg Mg");
name.add("Su Su");
name.add("Zaw Zaw");
name.add("Kyaw Kyaw");
name.add("Mya Mya");
```

Comment: " I can't get the same people to get the same thing if i run the second time." - are you sure that you want the same people to have the "same" thing each time you run the program?

Comment: The idea behind random number is the same person not getting the same thing again.

Comment: Try using a dictionary in any case...

Comment: shuffle your list, convert it to stack, and pop element and assign it to person

Comment: maybe what he meant is that he does not want a person to receive the same prize twice in a row? but i am not sure.

Comment: What i meant was I don't want the same people to get the same thing twice. So sorry for my grammar mistake @WhoAmI

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean @ZerO

Comment: What I meant was I don't want to get same people to get the same thing twice. It must be different. Sorry for my grammar mistake. @WhoAmI

Comment: Thanks so much @MH09. How can i display them like
Mg Mg>>>________
Su Su>>>_________
Zaw Zaw>>>_______
Kyaw Kyaw>>>_______
Mya Mya>>>__________

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    name.add("Mg Mg");
    name.add("Su Su");
    name.add("Zaw Zaw");
    name.add("Kyaw Kyaw");
    name.add("Mya Mya");

    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("Iphone");
    items.add("mp3");
    items.add("tv ");
    items.add("Iphone4");
    items.add("Iphone5");

    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
```

Every time you have to generate Random number, you have to save rand number into DB/file. And check that new generated no is in file or not. If it is not there then use that number for mapping and it is there then generate again the number.

Comment: he can also use a map to store names and values. Map<name,List<gifts>) where both name and gifts are Strings would do it.

Comment: How can I display or show afterwards? Thanks so much. @WhoAmI

Comment: @user3603441 - each time you make a draw (get a value for a person), check whether the value exists for that user by doing map.get(userName) and contains("String"). If yes, call random again. else, add it to the list .

Comment: Can you write for me with language code? I am still a basic learner of java and it is the first time i have heard the method called map.get(userName). Can you help me pls? Thank you so much. @WhoAmI